# Sequential criterion to prove limit point

Tags: real-analysis

Want to show if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has limit $L$ at $0$ and $L$ is not in the range of $f$, then $L$ is a limit point of the range of $f$.

I require some help for this question.

Let $y_n$ be a sequence in the range of $f$ that converges to $L$. We need to show that there exists a sequence $x_n$ in the domain of $f$ such that $x_n\to 0$ and $f(x_n)=y_n$ for all $n$.

Since $y_n$ is a sequence in the range of $f$, there exists a sequence $x_n$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$ for all $n$. Since $y_n\to L$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=L$.

By the sequential criteria for limits, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$. But we also have $f(x_n)=y_n$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=L$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$.

Is this enough?

And can we just say any epsilon neighborhood around L will intersect $f(x_n)$ ?

Comment: $f(\frac  1n) \to L$. Take $y_n=f(\frac  1n)$.